# How to use savefiledialog in vb.net -Please help me

Tags: vb.net, textedit

I have a program called TextEditPro and I just started it, I'm running into a problem.

When I had the code for clicking Save As... I don't know how to use the savefiledialog so when you click Save As it will pop up!

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not repeat questions, If you are not happy with the earlier questions answer, request clarification or edit your previous question so that it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/ec63bda3-cb9f-438f-8d3d-43eb858299aa. I hope it helps. The code works.